# Invoking callable with optional parameters

Tags: php, function, oop

The `set_error_handler` function in PHP invokes the user to invoke a callable as the first function argument. I've written a class that some instructions has to be done before this other function can be invoked. I've written it like this:

```
$errorCollector = new ErrorCollector();
set_error_handler(
    call_user_func_array(
        array($errorCollector, 'collect'),
        array(function($error) {
            //some instructions with $error
        }))
);
```

The `collect()` function from the `$errorCollector` class is getting called, which requires one non-optional parameter, which is a function.

The `collect()` function has 4 other parameters, `$errno`, `$errstr`, `$errfile`, and `$errline`. These are parameters that get filled in with error information in the `set_error_handler` function. When invoking a callable with these parameters in the `set_error_handler` function, you don't need to fill these in.

The class with the function looks like this:

```
class ErrorCollector
{
    private $errors;

    public function collect(callable $handleError, $errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline)
    {
        $error = array(
            'number' => $errno,
            'string' => $errstr,
            'file' => $errfile,
            'line' => $errline,
        );
        $this->errors[] = $error;
        call_user_func($handleError, $error);
    }
}
```

When I run my piece of code, I get the following error:

> Warning: Missing argument 2 for ErrorCollector::collect() in
>   C:\ErrorCollector.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Missing argument 3 for ErrorCollector::collect() in
>   C:\ErrorCollector.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Missing argument 4 for ErrorCollector::collect() in
>   C:\ErrorCollector.php on line 13
>
> Warning: Missing argument 5 for ErrorCollector::collect() in
>   C:\ErrorCollector.php on line 13

(Shortened the file URL's for better reading)

Why do I get this error while the parameters are optional for the `set_error_handler` function? Can I invoke a callable with optional parameters?

Comment: `ErrorCollector::collect` have 5 required arguments. But you pass only one - `array(function($error) {   //some instructions with $error }))`

Comment: @maximkou Yes, but how do i make the other 4 optional? Since these are optional in the `set_error_handler` function.

Comment: set default values for arguments. Like this: `public function collect(callable $handleError, $errno = null, $errstr = null, $errfile = null, $errline = null)`

Comment: @maximkou Will these parameters still get filled in when `set_error_handler` is called?

Comment: See answer. You wrong define error handler.

Answer (score 0):

You wrong define error handler. Define like this:

```
set_error_handler(
    array($errorCollector, 'collect'),
);
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, it will just throw an error that you're not giving the right arguments into the `set_error_handler` function.